# How do I make this question specific enough to be opened?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

The title is [Methodology used in Climate models](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/290401/methodology-used-in-climate-models)

This is annoying and I hate to do this, but I am looking for answers from experts working in the field who have spent several years studying this subject. It is a huge topic and It is definitely not easy to get into. Is it by default that such questions are banned in this site? Is there anything I can do? Because as far as I am concerned it is a very precise question.

Comment: I would just look for a good PhD thesis (or a few) on the subject and read the intro/take the papers cited in the intro ...

Comment: @Sanya Thanks for your help, I would probably have to do that at somepoint, but I don't understand why this question cannot remain open on this site.

Comment: A review article on a topic like that is a substantial manuscript (equivalent to a short to medium length *book*). Asking for a review on the site is an obvious no-go. I've never liked our policy on books and resource recommendation tags (they should be simply off limits as opinion based), and don't have an opinion about it's applicability (i.e. your first try).

Answer (score 2):

An elementary approach to your question would be on the size of several textbooks, and it is nowhere *near* a "very precise question".

If you want your question to be reopened, one approach is to simply make it a resource-recommendation question asking for good introductory textbooks to atmospheric and climate science.

However, if you think you can get an understanding of said "methodology" (because yeah, sure, there's only one such methodology, right?) without some serious study, then I'm afraid you're in for a rather steep disappointment.